# Using TeamCity against TFSPreview.com. Any success?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity, tfsbuild

I want to get a basic build going using TeamCity against TFSPreview.com.

The TFSPreview service uses LiveID for credentials, so as far as I can work out you'd need to associate the TeamCity build server login with a liveID using http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/online-id-providers  .

Googling for TFSPreview and TeamCity brings very little back. The only JetBrains issue I can find on the subject ( http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20909) is still open, and a fix version of 8.0.

Therefore, to potentially save me wasting time, **Is it currently possible to run a TeamCity (7.1) build against code stored in TFSPreview?**

NB: We cannot use the TFSPreview's own cloud based Hosts as the build machine, since we use some DevExpress components which need to be installed on the build machine - not an option using TFSPreview. It's a shame as otherwise this process has proven to be really rather simple (even if the build emails are slow to arrive).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your TFS Service account you can setup a service account specifically for these scenarios.

[image]

Comment: Hi @jesse , this does look promising - thanks for the reply. I hadn't seen this page, and haven't as yet set up an account for the build server its self, which I guess is needed here... So, once done, and the alternate credentials enabled, then I presume these are then used when setting up a new VCS Root in TeamCity? (I'm trying it now anyway)

Comment: You could let the build account use your alternate credentials or indeed setup your own. I'm not familiar with the team city side of things. You might also need to install the latest forward compatibility gdr or team Explorer anywhere...

Comment: Not forgotten this... Testing authentication in TC shows "The request failed with HTTP status 400: TF253023: You must update your client with the Forward Compatibility Update in order to connect to the Team Foundation Server that you selected. To obtain this update, go to the Microsoft Web site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166482.", and running the installer in the link brings "The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the windows installer because the program to be patched may be missing..." What a mire...

Comment: I think I'm going to have to mark this as the answer. I still cannot get path the error in my previous comment (I don't have TFS installed on my build server..), but it definitely set me in the right direction. If I ever get past this *&^%&* error I'll post up what I did to get round it..

Comment: Jetbrains have just updated the support issue I raised with them, and state that there are no workarounds, and have stated a fix version of 8 (of TeamCity - currently 7.1.3 while I type this). So looks a no-go.
If I get anywhere I'll update this again...

Comment: TeamCity now (7.1.4) adds support for tfsPreview.com, according to the TeamCity [Blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/07/teamcity-7-1-4-build-24331-is-ready/). In the previous 7.1.3 build this was not possible. Though at the time of writing I have yet to try this, it looks like there is at least some hope!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this works after managing to configure Teamcity thanks to @jesse's answer!
(I'm using the latest version of TC - 8.0.3)

I've added this as a full blown answer, because I also got stuck working out the URL and username format to use. So here are the full details that worked for me:

1. First configure alternate credentials in TFS (profile -> credentials -> enable alternate credentials)
2. Then in TeamCity:

   - Use the following URL format: **https://{yournamehere}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection**
   - For the username use the alternate credential name you setup in step 1. BUT put it in the following format "**##LIVE##\usernamehere**" (It actually tells you this below the box, but I somehow missed it first time!)

Hope this helps someone else!